# Zend classes not found when using them outside modules

Tags: php, class, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a forum I've put in the public directory and I want to make a SSO with the site and the forum. The problem is, when I try to get a user session using Zend's `AuthenticationService` class, it gives the following error :

> Class 'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' not found in C:\Users\Milen\Documents\site\public\forum\admin\sources\classes\session\ssoPublicSessions.php

What am I doing wrong ?
The code:

```
<?php

use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

class ssoPublicSessions extends publicSessions {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if (self::$data_store['member_id'] OR $this->_member->is_not_human) {
            return;
        }

        $auth = new AuthenticationService();
        $member = $auth->getIdentity();

        if (!$member) {
            return;
        }

        self::setMember($member['member_id']);

        $this->_updateMemberSession();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How should it find the classes? Need some more context here. What loads this class? Have you initialised the ZF application to setup autoloading?

Comment: It's an sso file inside the forum app, and no, I haven't initialized autolading.

Comment: No autoloading? So your application couldn't find file for that namespace.

Comment: You'll need to setup some auto loading... do you use `composer` for the project? If so, just include the `/vendor/autoloader.php` file and it should kick in (you might need to set up the autoloading of your own application by putting an [entry in to your `composer.json` file](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload))